# Can we move the filter to the right side

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to shift the filtering to the right hand side but not able to. Can anyone please help. please refer the expected output. Is it possible to achieve this?

reprex below

````
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
selectInput("Tic","Ticker",choices = c("","ALL",as.character(iris$Species)),selected = NULL)
dateRangeInput("Date","Date",start = '2016-01-01', end = Sys.time(),format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
DT::DTOutput('SUMMARY_GENERAL_table')


output$SUMMARY_GENERAL_table <- DT::renderDT( datatable(iris) )
```
````

Expect Output :
[image]

Comment: Thanks:),...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add some css. Please check the following:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
div(style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; float:right;", 
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6, selectInput("Tic","Ticker",choices = c("", "ALL", as.character(iris$Species)), selected = NULL)),
      column(width = 6, dateRangeInput("Date","Date",start = '2016-01-01', end = Sys.time(), format = "yyyy-mm-dd"))
      ))

DT::DTOutput('SUMMARY_GENERAL_table')
output$SUMMARY_GENERAL_table <- DT::renderDT( datatable(iris) )
```
````

[image: Result]